# cannot generate view binders java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I get the following error when using the data binding library. I've Googled it but it looks like it is a new error. Does anyone know what causes it?

```
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: failure, see logs for details.
cannot generate view binders java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at android.databinding.tool.ext.ExtKt.androidId(ext.kt:76)
    at android.databinding.tool.writer.LayoutBinderWriterKt$readableName$2.invoke(LayoutBinderWriter.kt:129)
    at android.databinding.tool.writer.LayoutBinderWriterKt$readableName$2.invoke(LayoutBinderWriter.kt)
    at android.databinding.tool.ext.LazyExt.getValue(ext.kt:27)
    at android.databinding.tool.writer.LayoutBinderWriterKt.getReadableName(LayoutBinderWriter.kt)
    at android.databinding.tool.LayoutBinder.<init>(LayoutBinder.java:203)
    at android.databinding.tool.DataBinder.<init>(DataBinder.java:52)
    at android.databinding.tool.CompilerChef.ensureDataBinder(CompilerChef.java:86)
    at android.databinding.tool.CompilerChef.sealModels(CompilerChef.java:200)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.writeResourceBundle(ProcessExpressions.java:149)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.onHandleStep(ProcessExpressions.java:82)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.runStep(ProcessDataBinding.java:154)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.access$000(ProcessDataBinding.java:139)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:66)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:145)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:93)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It looks like this is the code that fails, I guess because `$$delegatedProperties.length` is 1.

```
@NotNull
public static final String getReadableName(BindingTarget $receiver) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull($receiver, "$receiver");
    return (String)readableName$delegate.getValue($receiver, $$delegatedProperties[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually it turns out that [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/master/compiler/src/main/kotlin/android/databinding/tool/ext/ext.kt#76) is the offending line:

```
public fun String.androidId() : String = this.split("/")[1]
```

Basically if your Android ID is missing a `/` it will crash. Yeay. By checking my source code I found that I had accidentally set the ID of an image to a data binding expression, instead of the source:

```
        android:id="@{data.image}"
```

It would be nice if the data binding library had actual error messages.

Comment: From the bottom of my heart, thank you! I was about to give up life as a programmer when I found that you had found the issue. Thank you.